# CSS form ie7 bug with margin left and float

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

This css code has troubles for ie7. In ie6 is a total absolute mess.
The problem is that the input textbox gets bellow label.[image]
Only work around is to float the div left but has problems then with sizing..

```
fieldset.label_side > label {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    padding: 18px 20px 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    clear: left;
    line-height: normal;
}
fieldset label{
        font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 20px 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #333;
}

fieldset.label_side > div {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 140px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    clear: right;
      display: block;
}

.box-block fieldset input{    
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

input.text{
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border : solid #eee 1px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    line-height: 32px;
   display: inline;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0px 0 0 5px;

}
```

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem is because of the input width 100%.. I am looking how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 and IE7 don't play nice when the display is set to "inline-block";

Try adding the following to your label's CSS rule:

```
fieldset label{
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

I would probably have a conditional sheet for IE browsers (usually how I deal with this problem). Here's a site that exlains the problem in better details than I ever could: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: label & input are both by default inline element. So, there no need to define inline on it

Comment: If he wants his label to have a specific width he will need to make it inline-block, I suspect that's what making his form look wonky. The display:inline is for IE (if I'm not mistaken) and the zoom:1 will trigger the hasLayout which then make it work.

Comment: Yes your are right BUT see the screen-shot label & input come side by side. May be the main reason is that inline default value is basline. So, sometime when there is height difference between inline-block / inline then we need to define vertical-align:top;

Comment: guys as i mentioned i believe the problem is with the width 100% as ie7 has problem  box-sizing no support

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to write `vertical-align:top` in your **label** & **input** . Write like this:

```
label, input{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that may work (it works for me) is to apply **negative margin at input (textbox)**... or fixed width for ie7 or to drop ie7 support.

I had the same problem and i hated to have extra divs for border etc!

So here is my solution which seems to work!

You should use a ie7 only stylesheet to avoid the starhacks.

```
input.text{
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border : solid #eee 1px;
    width: 100%;
    -box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;

    *line-height:32px;
    *margin-left:-3px;
    *margin-right:-4px;
    display: inline;   
    padding: 0px 0 0 5px;

}
```